# Loading an image url into an item ListView using paging, Android

Tags: android, listview, paging

I`m trying to make a lisView with two textView and an imageView (that come as a url Sting) on each item at the list but, the list is not scrolling as good as I want, because its taking too long to load the image url. 
Im using an AsyncTask class for loading the the image but still it dosen`t look so good. 
here is my code at int the ArrayAdapter class:

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {

final private Context context;
final private Movie[] movies;
ImageView movieIcon;
TextView name, description;
Bitmap bitmap;

public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, Movie[] movies) {
    super(context,R.layout.item_in_movielist, movies);
    this.context = context;
    this.movies = movies;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_in_movielist, parent, false);


    name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvMovieName);
    description = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvMovieDescription);
    movieIcon = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ivMovieIcon);

    GetImageAsync getImageAsync = new GetImageAsync();
    getImageAsync.imageView = movieIcon;

    name.setText(movies[position].getMovieName());
    description.setText(movies[position].getMovieDescription());

    getImageAsync.execute(position);

    return rowView;
}

public class GetImageAsync extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
    public ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap1) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(movies[params[0]].getMovieImgURL());
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

I understood that this is **not** the way to do that, I`m looking for changing my code into "Paging" and I want to do it right. 
any tips what can I do ?

P.S
**If you can show me how to add Paging to this code it will be great.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(img.get(pos).replaceAll(" ", "%20"))
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .noFade().resize(70, 70)
            .into(v.image);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick replay, should I use it instead the AsynTask class or inside it?

Comment: Yes use this instead of AsynTask class